# How to remove space between list item in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

[jasper report result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4W1m.png)

I found that problem is with this PROPERTY_FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES property. If I set it to true in JRHtmlExporter, then space disappears, but it also affects all reports in a very bad manner. So I tried to put it in jrxml file, but nothing changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="...">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.frames.as.nested.tables" value="true"/>
```

**UPDATE**

I have a main report that contains a few subreports including my-list.jrxml that must have FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES `true`, but the rest reports must remain `false`.

So I set `htmlExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES, Boolean.FALSE);` (this is main report), 
but in `my-list.jrxml` I wrote `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.frames.as.nested.tables" value="true"/>`

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What surprise's me is that this property should **default** to `true` [Jasper report API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/DocxReportConfiguration.html#PROPERTY_FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES), so setting `true` will not change it!

Maybe your changed something else?, you have another problem!

Checkout also this property:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.emtpy.space.between.rows
```

ps. the `emtpy` is a famous typo in jaser report!, its not mine ; ) ds.

**EDIT:** User found that he was setting false during export, so what ever he put in the property will be override during export.., so how can I set it `true` when I need, and the rest of the time `false`, without changing the other reports?

You can access the properties of JasperReport on the  `JasperReport` object

So after compilation before you fill you can do something like this

```
String myProperty = jasperReport.getProperty("my.property");
if (myProperty!=null && myProperty.equals("specialValue")){
        //What ever you like don't set it false for example ....
}
```

and now just set in jrxml.

```
 <property name="my.property" value="specialValue"/>
```

when you want the `if` to execute

Comment: but if I make this 
`JRHtmlExporter htmlExporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
...
htmlExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES, Boolean.TRUE);
`
spaces disappears

Comment: That call is deprecated, however I think the issue is in the ... code, I suggest you post in question all your settings in JRHTMLExporter

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I found the line where `FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES` is set to `false`, but why property from jrxml file doesn't override it ?

Comment: Beacuse you are setting later!!,  Note... you can get the property from jasperPrint... so you can set your own one's and then do your logic during export..

Comment: Edit my post to show you how you can controll export parameters from single jrxl file...

Comment: but my report is a subreport and if a set a property to jasperReport, it will affect all ?

Comment: Yes, it will affect all, the PROPERTY is saying how to render the whole report.. Have you tried the property that I showed in answer?, you really need to help me out, with as much relevant code and info as possibile in the question...

Comment: Have you tried removing the property from htmlExporter and only setting the property in the main.jrxml to false..., if this does not work we need to find another work around, put the realtive html of my-list in the question